# How to obtain elements of an array close to another array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization, least-squares

There must be an easier way to do this, optimization method is also welcome. I have an array 'Y' and many parameters that has to be adjusted such that Y nears zero (= 'X') as given in the MWE. Is there a much better procedure to minimize this difference? This is just an example equation, there can be 6 coefficients to optimized.

```
x = zeros(10,1)
y = rand(10,1)
for a=1:0.1:4
    for b=2:0.1:5
        for c = 3:0.1:6
            z = (a * y .^ 3 + b * y + c) - x
            if -1<= range(z) <= 1
                a, b, c
                break
            end
        end

    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe

```
 p = polyfit(y,x,2);
```

is what you are looking for.
where p will be an array of your [a, b, c] coefficients.

Comment: No. a,b,c should take values in a range.

Comment: `polyfit` solves a minimization program -- the model is a polynomial function of `y`, and you have some test data `{y_i}_{i=1}^N`.  `polyfit` does not restrict the range of `a,b,c`.  You can, instead, write out the minimization program with constraints on `a,b,c`, and use `fmincon` or some other solver to find `a,b,c` that minimizes distance between data and model (`L2` norm) subject to the constraint that `a,b,c` are in a particular range.  See Boyd's notes on constrained least squares:  http://stanford.edu/class/ee103/lectures/constrained-least-squares/constrained-least-squares_slides.pdf